# why FXMLLoader giving error when used to load a FXML file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader, getresource

I was following a JavaFX tutorial and wrote the following code.

All the required header files are imported.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Number Generator");
        primaryStage.show();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

Main.fxml (created using SceneBuilder)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button id="button_generateRandomNumber" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="212.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateRandom" text="Generate Random Number" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#1e4d0e" />
      <Label fx:id="message" layoutX="112.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="258.0" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

StackTrace

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x5d85fddd) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x5d85fddd
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have tried every combination with getResource("Main.fxml") including relative and absolute path in every way possible still I am getting the error.
code is 100% same as of that tutorial.

Comment: As the exception message says "unnamed module @0x5d85fddd" I guess you didn't provide a module-info. Was this intended? How do you start the application (module-path, classpath etc.)?

Comment: Which JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: I am using javafx sdk 11.0.2 , I don't know about your first comment.

Comment: in VM arguments I wrote     --module-path "D:/softwares/development/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls        in Classpath I added javafx library as user defined library

Comment: Can you try either: provide a module-info (recommended if possible) or not exending the Application class from your Main class: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular

Comment: I didn't created module-info file when I started new project

Comment: You need (at least) `--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Comment: same underlying reason as the duplicate (which has an excellent answer, btw!) - just for module fxml instead of media

Answer (score 0):

In order to *javafx* work, you need to either download and import *javafx sdk* to your project or specify *dependency*, if you are using build tool like *Maven* or *Gradle*.

**Moreover** you need to add required modules (in this case *javafx's .jars*) either by using *module-info.java* and specifying required modules there, or adding modules to *VM arguments* - https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx.

*Bonus:*
Note that *javafx* was present in *JDK* up to version **10**. Since version **11**, they removed it. That is why you need to import javafx somehow to your project.